# How can you group a list extracted from queryset many-to-many field?

Tags: python-3.x, django, group-by, orm, many-to-many

I have a model that describes the essence of a **TV channel**:

```
class ChannelCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.name

class Channel(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(ChannelCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['category']

def __str__(self):
    return '%s: %s' % (self.category, self.name)
```

I also have a model that describes the essence of the **tariff**. Channels are linked to a tariff using a relationship **many-to-many**.

```
class Tariff(models.Model):
channels_list = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, blank=True, db_index=True, symmetrical=False)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.name
```

If I call the tariff object, I can get a **list of channels** that are assigned to it:

```
queryset = Tariff.objects.prefetch_related('channels_list')
for tariff in queryset:
    channels_list = [tariff.channels_list.all()]
     print (channels_list)
```

And get the next set:

> <QuerySet [<Channel: channelcategory1: channel1>, <Channel: channelcategory1: channel2>, <Channel: channelcategory2: channel3>]>

I want to receive queryset the following form:

> <QuerySet [<Channel: **channelcategory1**: channel1, channel2>, <Channel: **channelcategory2**: channel3>]>

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this question, everything is very simple. So, we need to do is create a handler in *providers/models.py* under the **class Tariff**:

```
def get_channels(self):
channels = list(str(p).split(':') for p in self.channels_list.all())
channel_list = []
for category, name in groupby(channels, lambda x: x[0]):
    channels_list_by_group = ";".join([channel[1] for channel in name])
    channels_list_by_category = (category + ":" + '\n' + channels_list_by_group + ". ")
    channel_list.append(channels_list_by_category + '\n' + '\n')
return ''.join(channel_list)
```

Pull on the template using this on **views.py**:

```
tariff = Tariff.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related('channels_list')
```

On html template: **{{ tariff.get_channels|linebreaksbr }}**
We will get what we need.

Then it's up to customization. For example, you can use *templatetags* in Django and make the display of information the way you need.